# Foreign key is null in one mapping entity

Tags: postgresql, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I was wondering why when I mapping two entity with `mappedBy`, in target class I have `ID` my member class, but in my member class I don't have target class `ID`. 
Example code:

```
 //class Onion
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "onion", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Potatoe potatoe;

//class Potatoe
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Onion onion;
```

And everything works fine, I have a bidirectional relationship. **But** on DB I noticed that class `Onion` doesn't has ID from `Potatoe`, but `Potatoe` has `Onion` `ID`. 
I know that when I want take potatoe object from onion object, persistence querying database for potatoe which has onion ID.

Why is it looking that? Is it possible to have potatoe `ID` in onion table?

Eclipslink 2.5.0
PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks this way, with only a single foreign key because you have only a single (bidirectional) relationship controlled by the Potatoe->Onion mapping, so it is represented with the Potatoe table having a foreign key to Onion. If you want another foreign key from Onion to potatoe, it would mean you are asking for a relationship that can be entirely independent of the Potatoe->Onion relationship.  This is easily done by just removing the mappedBy designator, which would make the Onion->Potatoe mapping completely independent and use its own foriegn key.  Your model then would have two unidirectional mappings that must both be maintained.